# Unable to select value from dropbox list in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to select a value from a dropbox.  I have tried with `XPath` and `ID` but seem unable to reach it

This is what I tried

```
var mySelectElm4 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlCountryOfBirth"));
var mySelect4 = new SelectElement(mySelectElm4);
mySelect4.SelectByText("Togo");
```

And this the html

```
<div class="form-object">
  <span class="error-star"></span>
  <div class="field-description input-placeholder styled field-description-show">Country of birth</div>
  <div class="field field-select">
    <select name="ctl00$plcMainArea$ddlCountryOfBirth" class="field-data selectCustom watermark hasValue" validate="validate" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="This field is required." placeholder="Country of birth" id="ddlCountryOfBirth">
      <option value="AF">Thailand</option>
      <option value="BS">The Bahamas</option>
      <option value="GM">The Gambia</option>
      <option value="TG">Togo</option>
      <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
      <option value="TO">Zambia</option>
      <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
    <span class="selectCustomBox">
      <span class="selectCustomBoxInner">Afghanistan</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="ddlCountryOfBirth_e" class="error-message"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
public void SelectIn(By by, string value)
{
    //code here to wait the element be displayed

    //after, the method will select the dropdown with the wanted value
    var dropDownListBox = _driver.FindElement(by);
    var clickThis = new SelectElement(dropDownListBox);
    clickThis.Options.First(o => 
        o.GetAttribute("id") == value || 
        o.Text.Equals(value) || 
        o.GetAttribute("value") == value)
    .Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to select by value

```
var mySelectElm4 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlCountryOfBirth"));
var mySelect4 = new SelectElement(mySelectElm4);
mySelect4.SelectByValue("TG");
```

Comment: @AutDev Is the dropdown inside iframe?

Comment: No, I dont think so... If that will be the case will it change something?

Comment: @AutDev Yes, it will. You need to switch to the frame in order to interact with elements inside it.

Comment: look for `frame` or `iframe` tags in the html.

Comment: Indeed I have found an Iframe tag

Comment: @AutDev Unfortunately its not ancestor of the dropdown. Is there any other frame or iframe which is  ancestor of the dropdown?

Comment: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/6125/pfs7Mb.png    Yes!!    I have used this and it seems to work!!

Comment: driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(); 
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame("iframMR");